# WHERE clause with a Max(Date) functionality in VBA, SQL Back-end, Access front-end

Tags: ms-access, vba

Within Access, I am trying to build a WHERE clause with a Max(Date) functionality, but it is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
strSQL1 = "Update tTbl_LoginSessions SET fldLogoutEvent = '" & Now() & "'" & _
 " WHERE fldUserName = " & IntMSIDAutoNum And fldLoginEvent = MAX(fldLoginEvent)
```

fldLoginEvent is the date/time in which the User Logged in
fldLogoutEvenr is the date/time in which the User will be logged out

Comment: Include `Debug.Print strSQL1`, then examine its output so you can see how you need to adjust the quoting.

Comment: And consider using a parameter query instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious correction:

```
strSQL1 = "Update tTbl_LoginSessions SET fldLogoutEvent = '" & _
           Now() & "'" & " WHERE fldUserName = " & IntMSIDAutoNum  & _
           " And fldLoginEvent =  (select top 1 fldLoginEvent from " & _
           " tTbl_LoginSessions )"
```

Comment: Yes this is first step, but MAX(fldLoginEvent) in WHERE clause will not work.

Comment: Missed the SQL back-end part. Edited my answer.

Comment: The question suggests `fldLogoutEvent` is a Date/Time field.  So for an Access query (unless it's pass-through type), the delimiters *must* be `#` instead of `'` regardless of whether it's a field in a SQL Server table.  But switching to a parameter query would avoid delimiter issues.  Or just include the literal function name `Now()` in the statement and let Access' db engine supply the value.

Comment: May be this: (select MAX(fldLoginEvent) from Tbl_LoginSessions )" ?

Comment: @Tim Williams, That seems to work, but it it selecting the the earliest Login date/time, not the latest(which is max).  
    Update tTbl_LoginSessions SET fldLogoutEvent = '11/18/2013 1:19:50 PM' WHERE fldUserName = 1 And fldLoginEvent =  (select top 1 fldLoginEvent from  tTbl_LoginSessions )

Comment: @ Tim Williams and HansUp, combo of the two answers worked.Thanks a million!